# Python List not recognizing variables as integers

Tags: python

The code is for Tic Tac Toe using Randint and lists. Could some one explain why there is an error? I've tried to change it to a interger and a string but it still doesn't work.

```py
import random 

boardt = [1, 2, 3]
boardm = [4, 5, 6]
boardd = [7, 8, 9]
print ("This is Tic Tac Toe / Noaughts and Crosses")
print ('(x)Human against (o) "machine"')
print (boardt)
print (boardm)
print (boardd)
hpos = int(input("Pick a position "))
if hpos == 1:
    boardt.remove(1)
    boardt.insert(0,"X")
    mpos = (int(random.randint(1,8)))
    if mpos == 1 or 2:
        boardt.remove(mpos)
        boardt.insert(mpos,"O")

    elif mpos == 3 or 4 or 5:
        boardm.remove(mpos)
        boardm.insert(mpos,"O")

    elif mpos == 6 or 7 or 8:
        boardd.remove(mpos)
        boardd.insert(mpos,"O")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    boardt.remove(mpos)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: In the case where mpos = hpos = 1, you're removing it twice: Once in boardt.remove(1) and another time in boardt.remove(mpos)

Comment: You need to ask first if the value is in the `list` (`x in list`) and then remove it otherwise you get a `ValueError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that e.g. `if mpos == 1 or 2` does not test if the value is 1 or 2.
The test should be `if mpos == 1 or mpos == 2:`, or better: `if mpos in (1, 2):`

Comment: Exactly, using and `int` as a condition will always return `True`, hence will always execute `if` block. +1

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX Unless that `int` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

`remove` removes by index, not value. However, you can replace that line and the following line with `boardd[mpos-6]="O"`. You should also clean up your code by using loops and a multidimensional array instead of 3 separate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with SuperStormer, that you should replace remove+insert with a simple assignment. That's not the main problem, though.

*if mpos == 1 or 2:* does not do what you think. That statement will always pass for True. What you want is *if mpos in (1, 2):*.

You can get out of a lot of if-coding by using a 2-dimensional array, like this: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]. Decide which one to set like this:

```
board = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
hpos = int(input("Pick a position "))
hpos -= 1  # Humans prefer to start at 1, computers at 0
x = hpos % 3  # Modulo to get column
y = hpos // 3  # Integer division to get row
board[y][x] = 'X'
for row in board:
    print(''.join(map(str, row)))
```